# Register same class for different types

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I have some classes which implement each of them its specific interfaces, but also a shared Interface. I need to be able to get each of them by its specific type where it is required, but also to get the list of the shared interface services.

```
//Classes
public class ClassA : IServiceA, IHealthReporter

public class ClassB : IServiceB, IHealthReporter

public class ClassC : IServiceC, IHealthReporter

public class Manager : IManager
{
    public Manager(IServiceA serviceA, IServiceC IServiceC)
    {
        //Works as expected
    }
}

public class HealthReporter : IHealthReporter
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IHealthReporter> _healthReporters;

    public Manager(IEnumerable<IHealthReporter> healthReporters)
    {
        //Getting an empty list here

        _healthReporters = healthReporters;
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> GetHealthStatus()
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach(var healthReporter in healthReporters)
        {
            result.Add(healthReporter.GetName(), healthReporter.IsHealtht().ToString());
        }

        return result;
    }
}

//Registration
builder.RegisterType<ClassA>().As<IServiceA>();
builder.RegisterType<ClassB>().As<IServiceB>();
builder.RegisterType<ClassC>().As<IServiceC>();

builder.RegisterType<Manager>().As<IManager>();
builder.RegisterType<HealthReporter>().As<IHealthReporter>();
```

These are the versions I'm using:

```
<package id="Autofac" version="4.8.1" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Autofac.Mvc5" version="4.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Autofac.WebApi2" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

I need to get all instances of type IHealthReporter.

How should I register those classes to be accessible using both types without registering more than once?

Comment: How would autofac know which class to provide when you request an IHealthReporter?

Comment: I need all of them, let me add the snippet where I use them.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. When you call scope.Resolve<IHealthReporter>(); what do you expect to receive? An instance of each class? 4 different objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let Autofac know those classes also implement `IHealthReporter` during registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<ClassA>().As<IServiceA>().As<IHealthReporter>();
builder.RegisterType<ClassB>().As<IServiceB>().As<IHealthReporter>();
builder.RegisterType<ClassC>().As<IServiceC>().As<IHealthReporter>();
```

or shorter:

```
builder.RegisterType<ClassA>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<ClassB>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
builder.RegisterType<ClassC>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Apart from that, the consumer (`HealthReporter`) and dependencies (`ClassA`, `ClassB` and `ClassC`) shouldn't be implementing the same interface, that's just odd and might be the reason why Autofac doesn't inject `HealthReporter` in `HealthReporter` as resolving it would result in an endless loop (or cause a stack-overflow).